# How to insert range of cards in database cell

Tags: java, database, poker

How can I insert a range of cards like AA-QQ (AA, KK, QQ) in a cell of a database?

I will use Java.

I can't use 2 columns like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463531/6942539) because cards aren't numbers.

**EDIT:**

Maybe I found. I can do a join.

Second table:

```
ID  CARD1  CARD2  CARD3
--  -----  -----  -----
1   AA     KK     QQ
```

But if I have four pair of card in next row?

Comment: post whatever you have done so far (code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to use two tables for this purpose.

```
MainTable:
Id    rest of the approoriate fields
1        ...........
2        ............

Card Event Table:
id main_table_id           order   card
1     1                      1       kk
2     1                      2       qq
3     1                      3       JJ
4     1                      4       AA
```

Here you can use foreign key to point to MainTable id.
That way you dont have to bother about number of cards